# How to get the voltage or temperature within FPGA?

Tags: voltage, fpga, artix-series-fpga

I am trying to test the reliability of a circuit design on my FPGA board. (using Vivado, Artix-7 xc7a35tcsg-c board).

The reliability here means the outputs of my circuit are expected to be persistent for the same input. However, many conditions and circumstances may affect the design reliability, such as aging, heating, and the voltage level of the input signals.

My plan is to keep feeding the same input signal and tracking the output to evaluate the reliability. And get the voltage or temperature at the same time.

And are there any methods to get/change the voltage or temperature?

For the temperature experiment, could I just put the board into a fridge or a cooler with a thermometer and report that temperature as the internal temperature?

I do not have much experience with FPGA.

Comment: What you do depends how accurate you want it to be. But yeah sure, you can do that. You will want to let the temperature soak a bit. You simply say "thermometer" but you should probably use a thermocouple taped to the FPGA. You can use a fridge but depending how long you run the test for it might be easier to just use a foam cooler with some very small holes cut into it with dry ice or cooling spray...mainly to try and avoid condensation. A temperature oven I used at work used tanks of CO2 to cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ds180_7Series_Overview) datasheet (emphasis added):

> XADC (Analog-to-Digital Converter)
> Highlights of the XADC architecture include:
>
> • Dual 12-bit 1 MSPS analog-to-digital converters (ADCs)
>
> • Up to 17 flexible and user-configurable analog inputs
>
> • On-chip or external reference option
>
> **• On-chip temperature (±4°C max error) and power supply (±1% max error) sensors**
>
> • Continuous JTAG access to ADC measurements

So, to answer the title question, it looks like the die is already instrumented and you just have to figure out how to use it. And it has JTAG access. On-chip sensing of temperature should be much more reliable than attempting to read the package temperature with an external sensor.

And yes, for testing you're going to want to use an environmental chamber and change the temperature by changing the environment.

Comment: Is it wise to test the environmental reliability of something by using self-tests from that thing?

Comment: @DKNguyen That's a valid concern. My guess is that other stuff  will fail first, but it sure wouldn't hurt to have independent backup measurements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how to change the voltage level without damage to the FPGA board?

Comment: You can use a programmable power supply. Lots of them have an interface such as LXI. Of course if you program the wrong voltage you could damage the FPGA.

Comment: You want to do the testing in a standard 1 cubic foot box. Another trick is to access a diode on the chip then reverse bias it with a small current and measure the resultant voltage. We would do this by placing the chip in an oil bath and stabilized it at several temperatures then did the measurement. It was extremely accurate. Once we had the slope that stayed the same for the process but the voltage was different with each lot. This was done for simple to very complex chips.

Comment: @Gil That's a great way of getting the actual chip temperature when you don't have a sensor on board. The two-current method  is even better (measure at I and I/10).